# How to get following date of the followers on twitter using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I need to create line chart for my twitter followers . I have used following code to list the followers details.

```
$parameters = array('include_user_entities' => true);
$response = $this->api->get('followers/list.json', $parameters);
```

Its working fine .But its doesn't probvide following date details. How can I get following date details using twitter api

Answer (score 0):

If you write:

```
$parameters = array('include_user_entities' => true);
$parameters = array();
```

The second command overwrite the first. Thus `$parameters` contains an empty array. Try with this:

```
$parameters = array('include_user_entities' => true);
$response = $this->api->get('followers/list.json', $parameters);
```

Comment: I removed the second parameter ...Its . But doesn't return  following date .

Comment: No... follower details are listed.But I want  to know which date the users for following me

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the API to tell when someone followed you.

Take a look at the API reference - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list

The only date in the returned object is `created_at` - that refers to when the account was created, not when it followed you.